# How to find the right path for gcc to locate libraries? Debian 7 Wheeze

Tags: c++, c, gcc, debian

How can I find the right path for a gcc command like that:

```
gcc -O2  -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXext -o viewer viewer.c
```

I have those libraries installed in /usr/include/X11 and /usr/include/X11/extensions.
I don't know with path to use for -lX11 and -lXext

It is a default debian 7 Wheeze instalation. No manual changes on paths or something like that

Comment: Did you try to add -I/usr/include/X11 and -I/usr/include/X11/extensions ? By the way, you do not have libraries in /usr/include, that's where header files are.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question with the solution that worked for you and accept it as solved.